# formatting string output with linebreaks and tabs in Python?

Tags: python, django, string, formatting, fixture

Im trying to extract some data from a large batch of files and convert them to a specific (JSON) format for importing into a database using Django Fixtures

I've been able to get this far:

'{    {\n        "pk":2,\n        "model": trials.conditions,\n        "fields": {\n            "trial_id": NCT00109798,\n            "keyword": Brain and Central Nervous System Tumors,\n        }{\n        "pk":3,\n        "model": trials.conditions,\n        "fields": {\n            "trial_id": NCT00109798,\n            "keyword": Lymphoma,\n        }{\n        "pk": 2,\n        "model": trials.criteria,\n        "fields": {\n            "trial_id":  NCT00109798,\n            "gender": Both,\n            "minimum_age": 18 Years,\n            "maximum_age": N/A,\n            "healthy_volunteers": No,\n            "textblock": ,\n        }\n\t\t"pk":2,\n\t\t"model": trials.keyword,\n\t\t"fields": {\n\t\t"trial_id": NCT00109798,\n\t\t"keyword": primary central nervous system non-Hodgkin lymphoma,\n\t\t}\n\t\t

...many lines later.....

After completion of study treatment, patients are followed every 3 months for 1 year, every\n      4 months for 1 year, and then every 6 months for 3 years.\n\n      PROJECTED ACCRUAL: A total of 6-25 patients will be accrued for this study.\n    ,\n        "overall_status": Recruiting,\n        "phase": Phase 2,\n        "enrollment": 25,\n        "study_type": Interventional,\n        "condition": 2,3,\n        "criteria":  1,\n        "overall_contact": testdata,\n        "location":  4,\n        "lastchanged_date": March 31, 2010,\n        "firstreceived_date": May 3, 2005,\n        "keyword": 2,3,\n        "condition_mesh": ,\n    }\n    \n    {\n    "pk": testdata,\n    "model": trials.contact,\n    "fields": {\n        "trial_id": NCT00109798,\n        "last_name": Pamela Z. New, MD,\n        "phone": ,\n        "email": ,\n    }}'

The output actually needs to look like this:

```
{
    "pk": trial_id,
    "model": trials.trial,
    "fields": {
            "trial_id": trial_id,
            "brief_title": brief_title,
            "official_title": official_title,
            "brief_summary": brief_summary,
            "detailed_Description": detailed_description,
            "overall_status": overall_status,
            "phase": phase,
            "enrollment": enrollment,
            "study_type": study_type,
            "condition": _______________,
            "elligibility": elligibility,
            "criteria": ______________,
            "overall_contact": _______________,
            "location": ___________,
            "lastchanged_date": lastchanged_date,
            "firstreceived_date": firstreceived_date,
            "keyword": __________,
            "condition_mesh": condition_mesh,
    }

    "pk": null,
    "model": trials.locations,
    "fields": {
           "trials_id": trials_id,
           "facility": facility,
           "city": city,
           "state": state,
           "zip": zip,
           "country": country,
    }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might have a look at the code for the management command 'dumpdata' in the source https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py#L111 because it has the option to indent  output which I gather you are trying to do

Comment: Formatting and indenting is irrelevant in JSON.

Comment: @pastylegs Unfortunately the data aren't coming from the DB so I can't use dumpdata.  Im taking an XML file and pulling out the relevant fields and outputting them in the Fixture JSON format using python.  

I'm basically returning one giant string with line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to json.dumps indent parameter:

Python has a pretty printer at http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html. It is extremely simple to use but only pretty prints python objects (You can't give it a json string and expect formatted output)

Eg.

```
pydict = {"name":"Chateau des Tours Brouilly","code":"chateau-des-tours-brouilly-2009-1","region":"France > Burgundy > Beaujolais > Brouilly","winery":"Chateau Des Tours","winery_id":"chateau-des-tours","varietal":"Gamay","price":"14.98","vintage":"2009","type":"Red Wine","link":"http://www.snooth.com/wine/chateau-des-tours-brouilly-2009-1/","tags":"colorful, mauve, intense, purple, floral, violet, lively, rich, raspberry, berry","image":"http://ei.isnooth.com/wine/b/7/8/wine_6316762_search.jpeg","snoothrank":3,"available":1,"num_merchants":10,"num_reviews":1}
from pprint import pprint
pprint(pydict)
```

The output is

```
{'available': 1,
 'code': 'chateau-des-tours-brouilly-2009-1',
 'image': 'http://ei.isnooth.com/wine/b/7/8/wine_6316762_search.jpeg',
 'link': 'http://www.snooth.com/wine/chateau-des-tours-brouilly-2009-1/',
 'name': 'Chateau des Tours Brouilly',
 'num_merchants': 10,
 'num_reviews': 1,
 'price': '14.98',
 'region': 'France > Burgundy > Beaujolais > Brouilly',
 'snoothrank': 3,
 'tags': 'colorful, mauve, intense, purple, floral, violet, lively, rich, raspberry, berry',
 'type': 'Red Wine',
 'varietal': 'Gamay',
 'vintage': '2009',
 'winery': 'Chateau Des Tours',
 'winery_id': 'chateau-des-tours'}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty printer in the json module.  Try something like this, `print json.dumps(s, indent=4)`.

```
>>> s = {'pk': 5678, 'model': 'trial model', 'fields': {'brief_title': 'a short title', 'trial_id':    1234}}

>>> print json.dumps(s, indent=4)
{
    "pk": 5678, 
    "model": "trial model", 
    "fields": {
        "brief_title": "a short title", 
        "trial_id": 1234
    }
}
```